# Weird value of key and value while debugging in hashmap source code

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, hashmap

When we put debugger inside the source code of Java 8 hashmap at the below line ,some weird value I am seeing for key and value like "file:///C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar". As per my understanding whatever value I am putting i should get that one while debugging.

Moreover when I tried on one of my colleagues machine the value of key is something different in debug mode.

```
final V putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent,
                   boolean evict) {
```

Comment: You need to provide example code, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a breakpoint inside a library function, you will get a debugger break each time it's hit. This includes code in the Java library that uses a HashMap for its own operation and logic. This is not unexpected. If you look at the call stack, you will see that it is associated with some kind of library code calling HashMap methods.

Please consider using breakpoint filters if available in your debugger and environment, or setting breakpoints in your own code and using "step in" to enter HashMap code from your HashMap calls (you may need to *dis*able step filters if present in your debugger)